# Linking Flash Professional Library Into Flash Builder

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, configuration, flash-builder4.5

I am currently working on an in-progress project using Flash Professional and Flash Builder. Before I began work, the project was already partially completed by another tech in both Professional and Builder--code written, timeline set, linkage created, etc. However, now that I'm on the project, I'm trying to set up the projects on my computer, but I can't seem to get Flash Builder to see the library provided by Flash Professional.

Code meant to access library items and import statements of packages like fl.controls are giving the "import could not be found" and "Type was not found" errors typically symptomatic of items missing from the library in Professional. However, I can verify that the items are there, they are linked to AS3 and set to be edited in Flash Builder. Moreover, I can compile the project through Flash Professional and everything will work without a problem, which is not true of compiling through Builder.

On the Builder side of configuration, I can verify that the project I am using has the correct path to the .fla file, and I know by looking at the other tech's configuration that I have all of the necessary SWC exports set up.

What am I missing to get the linkage configured correctly?

Comment: Did you check that the path names to the libraries are correct in the project settings section?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your problem correctly.

Here is how I use symbols from a .swf file in [my Flex application](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/):

```
package {
    public class Assets {
        [Embed('assets/Pref.swf', symbol='spades')]
        public static const SPADES:Class;

        [Embed('assets/Pref.swf', symbol='clubs')]
        public static const CLUBS:Class;

        [Embed('assets/Pref.swf', symbol='diamonds')]
        public static const DIAMONDS:Class;

        [Embed('assets/Pref.swf', symbol='hearts')]
        public static const HEARTS:Class;

        [Embed('assets/Pref.swf', symbol='kuku')]
        public static const KUKU:Class;

        [Embed('assets/Pref.swf', symbol='train')]
        public static const TRAIN:Class;

        [Embed('assets/Pref.swf', symbol='waggon')]
        public static const WAGGON:Class;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
        var sprite:Sprite = new Assets[mcName];
        addChild(sprite);
```

or:

```
        private static const WAGGON:Sound = new Assets.WAGGON;
        private static const TRAIN:Sound = new Assets.TRAIN;
```

Comment: Hey I've used that all the time in past project and it used to work fine. However, with the new version of FB4.7 I seems to run into run-time issues:  TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@112825e1 to com.mika.buttons.Button.
 at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
 at flash.display::Sprite()